# Where are the database username and password stored?

Tags: 8, database

I'd like to send my Drupal installation to a colleague, but I don't want him to see the username and the password of my database. Where are these informations stored?

I've seen that the username and the password are written in sitename/sites/default/settings.php, but is it the only file with these informations? Is it sufficient if I change the username and the password in this file and then send my colleague all my Drupal files and my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO both previous answers (posted with 10 secs difference ...) are incomplete ...

The `/sites/default/settings.php` file indeed does contain that userid and password, and if you "*don't want him to see the username and the password of my database*" (as in your question), then you at a minimum remove that userid and password (which you want to keep secret) in that file.

However, your question also contains this:

> Is it sufficient if I change the username and the password in this file?

To keep your userid and password secret you are done with only this change. But if you want your colleague to be able to actually ***use*** the Drupal installation you want to send, then IMO the answer to that question is NO. Because Drupal requires that the `/sites/default/settings.php` file that your colleague will be using contains the userid and password that matches with the database after it is restored by your colleague.

**Note** (credits: [sanzante](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2604/sanzante)): you should also send your colleague a database dump. And your colleague only has to import the database and edit the `settings.php` and add the user and password for the imported database. That config (user and password) is not dumped in the database so the colleague must have his/her own.

Comment: Yes, he also should send him a database dump and his colleague only has to import the database and edit the settings.php and add the user and pass for the importad database. That config (user and pass) is not dumped in the database so the collegaue must have their own.

Comment: @sanzante : merci! You agree I include your comment in my answer also?

Comment: Yes, I agree, no problem at all!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens and sanzante you both are right. Actually we miss some points :)

Comment: @Smalution : merci (also)! And sorry for my (constructive intended) critique to your answer (IMO not wrong, only incomplete), which was too tempting to just let it go without supplementing it.

Comment: No no, As I believe true is always true. I saw lots of your answer. Its always more details and descriptive. Which is easy to understand. Its great as usual.

Comment: This is just wrong. A mysqldump does not contain a database username and password so your conclusion that the answer is "NO" makes no sense. The answer is "YES".

Comment: Not sure why the other answers are incomplete?  The last sentence in the question clearly states that the OP is sending off files+database.

Answer (score 3):

The settings are stored in `sites/default/settings.php`. That is indeed the only file with that information and it is sufficient that you change the username and the password in that file.

Answer (score 3):

In a single word "YES". Is sufficient if I change the username and the password in `sitename/sites/default/settings.php`.