# In which file is the username/password located?

Tags: database, configuration

I did a standard installation of drupal 8 varbase and added this into Aqucia Dev Desktop 2.

Where can I find the username/password which is used for the database access from Drupal for the database? I looked into the settings.php but could not find any of this.

To be more specific. Below is the COMPLETE settings.php file without all the comments.

```
$databases = array();
$config_directories = array();
$settings['hash_salt'] = '';
$settings['update_free_access'] = FALSE;
$settings['container_yamls'][] = $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/services.yml';

$settings['file_scan_ignore_directories'] = [
  'node_modules',
  'bower_components',
];

$settings['entity_update_batch_size'] = 50;

// <DDSETTINGS>
// Please don't edit anything between <DDSETTINGS> tags.
// This section is autogenerated by Acquia Dev Desktop.
if (isset($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR']) && file_exists($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] . '/loc_inzicht_dd.inc')) {
  require $_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] . '/loc_inzicht_dd.inc';
}
// </DDSETTINGS>
$settings['install_profile'] = 'varbase';
```

As the site name is named "Inzicht" I expect to find an option in devdesktop but could not find it.

[SOLVED]
I did a long scan over the complete HDD and found the connection string in
C:\Users\.acquia\DevDesktop\DrupalSettings

Comment: I already looked at that question and as I mentioned in the question, the username/password is not in the settings.php.

Comment: definitly not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not stored in a file, they're both stored in the `users_field_data` database table. The password is stored as a salted hash, you won't be able to reverse engineer it.

Varbase does make some changes in its install profile; it sets the default username to "webmaster" instead of "admin", and locks that field so it can't be altered.

So your username is "webmaster", and your password is whatever you set it as during the installation process.

Comment: Your answer is correct but my question was not. I need the username/password for the sql connection. Sorry for this

Comment: @Justme you can configure database connection in settings.php file located under `sites/default/settings.php` but in that case this question looks like to be a duplicate, have a look: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225477/where-are-the-database-username-and-password-stored